# Running a python for loop iteration for 5 seconds

Tags: python, time, delay

The following code runs the `main` function and sleeps for exactly 5 seconds - time spent to run the function.

```
starttime = time.time()
timeout = time.time() + 60 * 2  # 60 seconds times 2 meaning the script will run for 2 
                                # minutes
while time.time() <= timeout:
        main()
        time.sleep(5 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 5.0))  # 5 second interval between 
                                                           # each new iteration
```

I am not sure how the code

> time.sleep(5 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 5.0))

ensures a 5 second interval.

Comment: if you're looking for a 5 second sleep why don't you just use time.sleep(5)..?

Comment: No actually i am looking to ensure that the loop runs for exactly 5 seconds which includes the time taken by main to execute

Comment: Got you. It sounds like you want to use signals to handle this case and implement a proper timeout.. Unfortunately not something I know much about though so can't tell you much more than that

Comment: Doesn't `main` block your while loop execution? If it blocks then you don't need to wait at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identified code ensures that `main()` is called every 5 seconds **ONLY IF** the execution of `main()` takes less than 5 seconds. This is because the modulo operator `%` in python computes the remainder of `(time.time() - starttime)` divide by `5.0` at each iteration of the `while` loop. This remainder is the execution time of `main()` in each iteration. Subtracting this from the `5` seconds gives a sleep time that result in the 5 second interval in calling `main()`.

The assumption here is that the time to execute `main()` is significant compared to executing any other line of code shown here. Under this assumption, to see that the remainder of `(time.time() - starttime)` divide by `5.0` is the execution time of `main()`, consider:

1. In the first iteration, `(time.time() - starttime)` is the time to execute `main()`, and if the execution of `main()` takes less than 5 seconds, this is the remainder when divided by `5.0`.
2. In the second iteration, `(time.time() - starttime)` is 5 seconds plus the time to execute `main()` in the second iteration because the sleep in the first iteration is such that `5.0` seconds elapsed between the calling of `main()` between the first and second iterations. Hence, the remainder of this divided by `5.0` is the time to execute `main()` in the second iteration.
3. In subsequent iteration `i`, it is clear that `(time.time() - starttime)` is `(i - 1) * 5` seconds plus the time to execute `main()` in the `i`-th iteration. Hence the argument from (2) holds for all iterations until the while loop exits.